# Hbase shell gives NativeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have configure hbase on my local machine, below are my jsp task

```
$ jps
17389 HQuorumPeer
16554 TaskTracker
17894 Jps
16362 JobTracker
15786 NameNode
16078 DataNode
16267 SecondaryNameNode
```

But when I hit

```
$ hbase shell
```

It gives me following error

NativeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

initialize at /home/rahul/hbase-1.2.4/lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:42

(root) at /home/rahul/hbase-1.2.4/bin/hirb.rb:131

Can any one help me to solve this error.I have wasted several hours to solve this error. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste the logs?

Comment: I have encountered that error when the configuration file that hbase uses does not point to the correct Zookeeper server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this error is very generic and can occur for a number of reasons. I recently experienced this using the `hbase` command on version `HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.16.1` when the wrong URI was configured in `core-site.xml` and `hbase-site.xml` (`fs.defaultFS` and `hbase.rootdir` respectively). The only way I diagnosed this was to try connecting programmatically via the Java API (e.g. by following https://www.baeldung.com/hbase), which gave me the full stack trace of the exception that caused the `NativeException`.